# Problem with resizing of the array. I need to delete zeros in the array and leave only digits which are not equal to 0

Tags: c#, resize

Don't understand the problem of resizing of the array. All I need to do is only deleting zeros from the array and leaving digits different from zero.

```
        int zeroCounter = 0;
        int SIZE = 30;
        var rand = new Random();
        int[] arr = new int[SIZE];
        foreach (int i in arr) 
        {
            arr[i] = rand.Next(0, 11);
            if (arr[i] == 0) 
            {
                zeroCounter++;
            }
            Console.Write(arr[i] + " ");
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
        arr = arr.Where(i => i != 0).ToArray();
        Array.Resize(ref arr, SIZE - zeroCounter);
        foreach (int i in arr)
        {
            Console.Write(arr[i] + " ");
        }
```

Comment: `arr = arr.Where(i => i != 0).ToArray();` will return a new array containing only numbers not equal to zero. You don't need to subsequently resize it - it will already be the correct size.

Comment: Also your initialisation of the array is incorrect. `foreach (int i in arr)` should be `for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)`. The `foreach (int i in arr)` will yield a sequence of zeros of length `SIZE` , because the array only contains zeroes at that point.

Comment: What is the purpose of `Array.Resize` here? `arr = arr.Where(i => i != 0).ToArray();` already achieves your stated goal.

Comment: The main problem is the initialisation of the array, which will repeatedly update `arr[0]` (and print its value) and not any other elements.